# Join two querysets in django but keeping their order?

Tags: python, django

```
class WordListView(ListView):
    model = Word
    template_name = 'vocab/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'words'
    current_user = self.request.user
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        all_words = Word.objects.filter(user=current_user)
        studying_words = all_words.filter(currently_studying=True).order_by('?')
        other_words = all_words.filter(currently_studying=False).order_by('?')
        return studying_words|other_words
    else:
        return Word.objects.none()
```

I tried using .join() and | and union, but none of them work because they're either outdated or doesn't keep the random order. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first order on the `currently_studying` field in descending order, and then in random order.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class WordListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Word
    template_name = 'vocab/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'words'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user=self.request.user
        ).order_by('-currently_studying', '?')
```

Since the `QuerySet` depends on another field, you need to override the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).